# Can a new domain name be easily added to an existing SAN SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm looking at getting an SSL certificate and I think the SAN type is what I need. However, Can I easily add further domain names to be covered by the certficate in the future. E.g. I have www.example.com on my server.  In 6 months time I decide to build and host a new site on the same server and give it the URL www.example2.com.  Would I then be able to add the new domain to the existing certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certificates cannot be changed after they are signed, otherwise they would provide no security.

Comment: What if it was a wild card one?

Answer (score 1):

Once issued, a certificate holds all SANs. This means that a certificate would have to be revoked and a new one has to be issued to add a new SAN.

You should first find out which names you want to register, because revoking and reissueing will most likely cost extra money.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to add domain in the existing SAN SSL Certificate, you can temporarily self-signed the certificate for the other domain you are thinking for and then at the time of expiration(after 1 or 2 year validity) you have to apply a new SAN to include your new domain name.